# Getting value from a TextBox after paste

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario like this where i have dynamically generated textboxes.
I have to validate the textbox for max 15 characters and restricting special characters.

Below is the code by which in document.ready() i am generating the textboxes and binding 
paste events to them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //Generate textboxes..i have some logic by which i am generating
  //textboxes on the fly and giving textboxes a class flagText
  GenerateFlagBoxes();

  //i am binding the textboxes by class names
   var $flagArea = $('.flagText');
    $flagArea.bind('paste', function () {
        var element = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert($(element).val());
        }, 100);
    });

});
```

But this is not working.The alert i provided is not coming.I think that the controls are created in the ready event can't
be bound to listen events.Am i wrong.I don't know why it is happening.
I want some suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

This fiddle is working.I am checking , i might be wrong some where.I will update where i 
am wrong;

http://jsfiddle.net/mnsscorp/8QFGE/1/

Yes now working .In the document ready i am able to bind paste event.I was wrong some where in the code. :)
Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () { ... });

Comment: see i have updated..thanks

Comment: Well, ignoring `GenerateFlagBoxes();`, the rest works fine. Any JavaScript errors? Is your '.flagText' selector actually correct? Or is `GenerateFlagBoxes()` generating boxes with incorrect class names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try event delegation for dynamically generated elements -

```
$(document).on('paste','.flagText',function(){
    var element = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert($(element).val());
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: You mean to say document ready handler....??  Yes, You can have as many handler's as you need(_if you really need_)

Answer (score 3):

For dynamic elements, you need an event delegate, such as [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Try this:

```
$("body").on('paste', '.flagText', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use target

```
var $flagArea = $('.flagText');
    $flagArea.bind('paste', function (e) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(e.target.value);
        }, 100);
    });
```